# C++ - Font Color, Size and Append Management

Tags: c++

I am making a console program that deals with the simple command line (console) in C++. It works fine, the program has no errors at all. My problem that came for design was: how can I instantiate in C++ changing the font size and color that would be displayed in the program? Suppose like this:

"Hello. This is the List Commands. Please Choose Wisely."

How can I make the font colored green while the others white? Set up the size?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: You didn't mention an OS. Windows has [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx), specifically [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200(v=vs.85).aspx), the latter not available on XP.

Comment: There is a Console API for Windows 32 bit OSs which you would need to use.  Older versions of Windows allowed for the use of escape sequences such as the ANSI escape sequences however newer versions of Windows such as XP and later do not support the ANSI sequences so you must use the Console API.  Start with this Wikipedia article for things to search for.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console

Comment: NCurses is also available for Windows, but perhaps the easiest solution might be to just use "conio.h" and an old Turbo-C DOS compiler.  "It depends" :)  But under *no* circumstances would I recommend ANSI.SYS.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, I'd recommend ncurses, hands-down:

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/